# JQtouch overrides divs to lose class because it namespaces 'active'

Tags: jquery, iphone, jqtouch

I am developing a jQuery app for iPhone.

The *strangest* behavior occurs when I'm dragging the view, the classes I have on my buttons are removed. There is *nothing* in the app that says to remove the classes.

Is there a known issue with this? Or an issue with dragging causing a page to refresh?

Comment: what class names are you using? might accidentally be using a class that some js lib makes use of

Comment: Did you roll your own drag-n-drop library, or are you using a jQuery UI + jqTouch combo? Perhaps you could also post the relevant code?

Comment: Using the class 'active'

Comment: YES! IT WAS jQTouch stealing the word 'active' as a class..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether you have a CSS class overriding the prevailing one upon drag.

Comment: JQ Touch actually steals this word from being used anywhere in your app. What a terrible idea.